# Accessing outer-query context as part of a GROUP BY to get a JOIN for a derived MIN value (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: Overview]

I have a fairly complex SQL statement that I use to oversee my properties (in real-estate) and have an issue getting the property code related to the minimum value.

These are my first rows from my actual statement (all the TBD should rather be the listing keys instead):

[image: SQL statement result-set]

```
totalusd    averageusd  minimum maximum stdev   occurence   province    category
$28,030,400,000.00  $663,379.79 EAD-1018: $0.02 BMX-7444: $425,000,000.00   $3,616,359.24   42254    Everywhere  All types
$1,121,940.00   $224,388.00     TBD: $63,000.00     TBD: $391,440.00    $117,795.00 5   Azua    Apartments for Sale
$460,000.00     $230,000.00     TBD: $160,000.00    TBD: $300,000.00    $98,994.95  2   Azua    Country-House for Sale
$5,343,870.00   $381,705.29     TBD: $130.00    TBD: $1,100,000.00  $313,827.57 14  Azua    Houses for Sale
$5,311,980.00   $279,577.79     TBD: $14.00     TBD: $2,973,230.00  $714,520.56 19  Azua    Land for Sale
$500,000.00     $500,000.00     TBD: $500,000.00    TBD: $500,000.00        1   Azua    Locals for Sale
$1,611,000.00   $805,500.00     TBD: $99,000.00     TBD: $1,512,000.00  $999,141.88 2   Barahona    Apartments for Sale
$2,700,000.00   $2,700,000.00   TBD: $2,700,000.00  TBD: $2,700,000.00      1   Barahona    Country-House for Sale
```

I need the actual property codes in lieu of the TBD in my results. As you can see, I am ok with the UNION subquery that displays which property is the minimum and the maximum for all the records that are not part of the GROUP BY. But, in the context of the GROUP BY, I grab the MIN value ok from the actual TABLE its on, but the property code is into another TABLE, and just can't get to it.

This is my statement:

```
SELECT TotalUSD, 
        AverageUSD, 
        CONCAT(CONCAT(MinimumCode, ': '), Minimum) AS Minimum, 
        CONCAT(CONCAT(MaximumCode, ': '), Maximum) AS Maximum, 
        Stdev, 
        Occurence, 
        Province, 
        Category FROM
(SELECT 'TBD' AS MinimumCode,
        'TBD' AS MaximumCode,
        CONCAT(SUM(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text, CONCAT(' ', norm3.otherinformation)) AS TotalUSD, 
        CONCAT((SUM(ass.advnormalizedprice)/COUNT(*))::numeric::money::text, CONCAT(' ', norm3.otherinformation)) AS AverageUSD, 
        COUNT(*) AS Occurence, 
        CONCAT(MIN(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text, CONCAT(' ', norm3.otherinformation)) AS Minimum,
        CONCAT(MAX(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text, CONCAT(' ', norm3.otherinformation)) AS Maximum, 
        CONCAT(STDDEV(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text) AS Stdev, norm1.jsonvalue AS Province, norm2.otherinformation AS Category,
        ass.category AS categoryId,
        ass.stateorprovince AS stateorprovinceId
    FROM public.listingassociation ass 
        JOIN normalizedjsonfield norm1 ON norm1.id = ass.stateorprovince 
        JOIN normalizedjsonfield norm2 ON ((norm2.jsonfield = 'IDXGeneratorConstants.ECategory') AND (norm2.jsonvalue = ass.category::varchar(255))) 
        LEFT JOIN normalizedjsonfield norm3 ON ((norm3.jsonfield = 'IDXGeneratorConstants.ECategory.defaultCurrencyPeriod') AND (norm3.jsonvalue = ass.category::varchar(255))) 
        FULL OUTER JOIN listingitem lst ON ((lst.id = ass.listingitemid) AND (lst.status = 1)) 
    WHERE (ass.advnormalizedprice IS NOT NULL) AND (ass.advnormalizedprice > 0) 
    GROUP BY norm1.jsonvalue, norm2.otherinformation, norm3.otherinformation, ass.transactiontype, ass.category, ass.stateorprovince
UNION SELECT (SELECT lst.listingkey FROM public.listingassociation ass JOIN listingitem lst ON lst.id = ass.listingitemid ORDER BY ass.advnormalizedprice ASC LIMIT 1) AS MinimumCode, 
            (SELECT lst.listingkey FROM public.listingassociation ass JOIN listingitem lst ON lst.id = ass.listingitemid ORDER BY ass.advnormalizedprice DESC LIMIT 1) AS MaximumCode, 
            SUM(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text AS TotalUSD, 
            (SUM(ass.advnormalizedprice)/COUNT(ass.*))::numeric::money::text AS AverageUSD, 
            COUNT(ass.*) AS Occurence, 
            MIN(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text AS Minimum, 
            MAX(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text AS Maximum, 
            STDDEV(ass.advnormalizedprice)::numeric::money::text AS Stdev, 
            ' Everywhere' AS Province, 
            ' All types' AS Category,
            NULL,
            NULL
    FROM public.listingassociation ass JOIN listingitem lst ON lst.id = ass.listingitemid WHERE lst.status = 1 AND ass.advnormalizedprice > 0 AND ass.advnormalizedprice IS NOT NULL) AS unionquery ORDER BY Province, Category
```

The part in the statement here needs to be replaced by something:

'TBD' AS **MinimumCode**,
'TBD' AS **MaximumCode**,

Yet, in the UNION subquery, this works:

(SELECT lst.listingkey FROM public.listingassociation ass JOIN listingitem lst ON lst.id = ass.listingitemid ORDER BY ass.advnormalizedprice ASC LIMIT 1) AS **MinimumCode**, 
(SELECT lst.listingkey FROM public.listingassociation ass JOIN listingitem lst ON lst.id = ass.listingitemid ORDER BY ass.advnormalizedprice DESC LIMIT 1) AS **MaximumCode**,

How should I populate **MinimumCode** and **MaximumCode** in the context of the **GROUP BY** so that it holds the Listing Key associated to the minimum and maximum value (not the minimum and maximum values themselves)?

I also attach the UML of my database tables here (to get a better understanding of the context).

[image: UML of TABLE interactions]

Thank you for hinting me in the right direction to resolve this issue.

As a side note, having the right property code associated with the MIN and MAX is an excellent diagnosis tool as mistakes often happen in limit cases (wrong currencies, prices per area rather than total price, etc.). I will then become able to look at that report and assess the sanity of my real-estate portfolio in a heartbeat, and then have actionable steps I can do with the property code at hand as part of the report rather than having to go through multiple steps to get it. As you can see in the SQL statement subset, I have 27 billion in property value to oversee, hence this is not a walk in the park to detect flawed listings.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) Reading suggestion: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN to the row in the table with the MIN or MAX values for a given set of criteria by including a subquery that returns the ID of the row you're interested in (similarly to how you have done in your UNION) and using that ID to JOIN to the table itself and get all of the values.

By doing this as a subquery, but not directly JOINing to it, it allows you to use columns from the tables in the parent query in the subquery, so in the WHERE clause of the subquery, you can compare as many columns as you like to those of the parent query to ensure get the MIN and MAX for the same categories as your GROUP BY.

See the below SQLFiddle example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09dd1/32/0

The example will allow you to select any fields from the listingitem that correspond to either the lowest or highest values for a given category (or any set of conditions you replace 'sCategory' with) and in turn, JOINs from lmin and lmax to other tables will return data relating to the MIN and MAX properties.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE listingassociation
(
   listingitemid int,
   advnormalizedprice decimal(7,2)
);

CREATE TABLE listingitem
(
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   listingkey varchar(10),
   sCondition varchar(10)
);


INSERT INTO listingassociation
  (
      listingitemid,
      advnormalizedprice
  )
 VALUES
   (1, 100),
   (2, 200),
   (3, 300),
   (4, 400),
   (5, 500);



 INSERT INTO listingitem
   (
      id,
      listingkey,
      sCondition
   )
 VALUES
   (1, 'AAA', 'A'),
   (2, 'BBB', 'A'),
   (3, 'CCC', 'A'),
   (4, 'DDD', 'B'),
   (5, 'EEE', 'B');
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    lst.id,
    lst.listingkey,
    lst.sCondition,
    ass.listingitemid,
    ass.advnormalizedprice,
    minval.id,
    minval.listingkey,
    maxval.id,
    maxval.listingkey

FROM
        listingassociation AS ass
  JOIN listingitem AS lst ON lst.id = ass.listingitemid
  JOIN listingitem AS minval ON minval.id = 
                                  (
                                      SELECT
                                          lmin.id
                                      FROM
                                          listingassociation AS amin
                                          JOIN listingitem AS lmin ON lmin.id = amin.listingitemid
                                      WHERE
                                         lmin.sCondition = lst.sCondition
                                      ORDER BY 
                                          amin.advnormalizedprice ASC LIMIT 1
                                  ) 
  JOIN listingitem AS maxval ON maxval.id = 
                                  (
                                      SELECT
                                          lmin.id
                                      FROM
                                          listingassociation AS amin
                                          JOIN listingitem AS lmin ON lmin.id = amin.listingitemid
                                      WHERE
                                         lmin.sCondition = lst.sCondition
                                      ORDER BY 
                                          amin.advnormalizedprice DESC LIMIT 1
                                  );
```

Comment: That only partially worked.  It is extremely slow hence a re-structured query should be better. But thanks for the input, although I do not feel it should close the issue.